# Samsung galaxy a7 2018 hangs after update android 10

Tags: samsung, screen, system-freeze, development, driving-mode

Recently I updated my device from android 9(one UI 1)to android 10(one UI 2)
After updating to android 10 it freezes again and again,not the whole phone freeze, only display hangs but background working properly, when i push power button and lock device, and after unlock by power button it works normal, but after sometime it freezes again. I repeat this task again for unfreezing.
I checked device logs for hangs reason, where I found

```
EGLNativeWindowType 0x79466cd890 disconnect failed
```

It looks like openGL problem, is some driver corrupt or missing in new update,

Samsung block downgrade from bootloader,So I have no choice,

Note:*I updated with latest ota update,there is no new update from Samsung,

*Device was working well with android 9 one ui1(means there is no hardware fault)

- Model: samsung sma750f

Answer (score 0):

Bro Downgrade by Odin.
Then it'll work nicely.
I've face same issue and after Downgrade it's working nicely.

Comment: Could you please describe how to do that? Not everyone is familiar with Odin (or knows what it is – some might turn to Heimdall (wow, cool, that exists indeed) or Asgard (huh?) in search ;)